# 2 OS's at once on the same computer?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-vista

Is it possible to run  Windows Vista on one hard drive and Ubuntu 14.04 on the other using the same computer?

Comment: Yes.  Many people dual boot make sure you backup first and take the time to carefully read all the questions you are asked during the install. The installer is designed to let you install side by side if you wish but will also replace Windows with Ubuntu if that's what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. see here [How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot)
and http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In fact I do that right now, You just have to go to the boot menu on start-up, and set the hard drive with the operating system you want to start up as the default. I have an XP, with an internal hard drive it is installed on. I have Ubuntu installed on an external hard drive, and I just choose which to start from. I use the f10 key to go to set-up, then I go to advanced and boot order, hard drives and change which one I want to start from.