# I want to install Ubuntu on a different Hard Disk Drive, will i be able to dual boot Window 7 and Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a spare Hard Drive Disk on my computer, I was wondering if I be able to use Ubuntu and be able to boot Window 7 when I want to or I do I have to do something in order for that to happen?
I don't want to mess up my computer again.

Please beware im installing Ubuntu on Window 7 not with a CD

Comment: For a new user willing to unplug a drive, it is easy to install Ubuntu to a second drive and run an update to add Windows to grub2's boot loader menu. If not willing to unplug drive you must use Something Else and manually choose partitions, and most importantly to install the boot loader to the Ubuntu drive. You want to keep the Windows boot loader. But boot from grub menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-optiond

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I exactly understand your intention. You can have either dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows 7 or you can set up a virtual machine of Ubuntu inside Windows 7 operating system. I guess you want the first.

When you install Ubuntu, the installer will offer you designing dual-booting, so there should be no problems in further use of Windows 7 after that in separate boot session.

Ubuntu is installed either from a CD or from a USB disk.