# Ubuntu Install 14.04 Dual Boot Dual Drive Win 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Currently I have 2 HDDs:

```
/dev/sda
 /dev/sda1 ntfs
 Free space
/dev/sdb
 /dev/sdb1
```

All of the install procedures don't seem to include a how-to for a dual drive PC.

Should the `/dev/sda` (currently only for Windows) be the "Device for boot loader installation"?

### I already have a pre-existing Ubuntu install which needs to be reinstalled but I don't know how to proceed.

7 hours later, thoughts, experience from a noob. YMMV.  Thanks for answer to my question Fabby.

Using the revert key on the partitioning screen always caused an error not necessarily immediately. Had to reboot from cd 15 mins, and delete to correct, then start over. 
Before I saw Fabby's answer, installing 'boot' on your second drive didn't work for me, though one of the links indicated otherwise. It might work, but as advised installing boot on sda
Even though boot loader is installed on sda, a boot partition is still needed on sdb
Success in less than a day. It was beautiful looking outide too.

Comment: I could not understand a word?????

Comment: Have you seen these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot AND: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-optiond

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: @Rmos: the last edit to your question should have been a comment or maybe even an answer...  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your first drive (`/dev/sda`) should be set as the device for the boot loader installation.

Make a [full system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before proceeding! (You've been promoted to user type 4)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)