# How to Dual Boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 15.04 Both On Separate Drives?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Last night I attempted to install Ubuntu to my secondary hard drive and dual boot Windows 10. It completely borked everything. Grub screwed me over. I think my grub is still messed up and I need to fix it. How would I go about install Ubuntu 15.04 to a secondary internal hard drive while still being able to boot to windows if need be on boot. Before windows 8 this was easy but with the way Microsoft changed everything it completely shoots me in the foot. I am installing the live iso to my usb by UNetbootin. Yes I have UEFI unfortunately.

Comment: Did you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: What brand/model system? Some are difficult to get to boot anything but Windows.  Best to partition in advance with ESP - efi system partition first and use Something else to choose / (root) partition. Or disconnect Windows drive and only install to second drive. Grub will only install to the ESP on sda, but should not conflict with Windows otherwise. also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Be sure to boot installer in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred I am using a Sager

Comment: @ubfan1 yes but I am on 15.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu must be installed after windows, because windows intentionally wipes any other bootloader than its own. Even though you install ubuntu on a second hard drive, the bootloader must be installed on the master hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the exact solution you're looking for, but my computer is set up so it by default boots straight into Ubuntu, but when I need Windows I hit f12 and select the other drive, which means less messing with GRUB.  Could something like that work?