# I want to install ubuntu on my external hdd

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu User. I would like to install ubuntu on my own external hdd.
When my hardisk connect to my laptop, I can use Ubuntu, like this without external hdd, I would like to use windows without any boot errors.

The question may be already answered but I cannot find the link. Please help me how to do that or give me a link already answered.

Thanks

bawlone89

Myanmar

Comment: Do you want a full install or a persistent live system?

Comment: You can easily accomplish this but you need to pay extreme attention while installing.  You'll install Ubuntu to the second hard drive, and install the bootloader also to the second hard drive.  As long as your system can boot from USB devices, you can select your drive from your bios bootloader and load Ubuntu.  Use extreme caution.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If BIOS, use this but be sure to change install of grub2's boot loader to drive sdb (or whatever it is). http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot