# Dual Boot for 2 OS on 2 different drives

Tags: dual-boot, drive

I've seen many topics with the same title but none seem to encounter the same issue as I do:

I have 2 drives:

**SSD 250GB**

- All for Windows 10

**HDD 1TB**
Partitioned in:

- 750GB - NTFS (for personal data)
- 100GB - Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (ext4)
- 4GB - Swap
- The rest remains unallocated

I expected to be able to manually choose the 1TB HD as the boot option from the BIOS in order to access the Ubuntu I just installed, however, when I pick that drive, the screen goes black and brings me back to the boot menu from the BIOS. I'm not sure if it's not recognizing any grub installed on that HD, or if it's detecting the NTFS partition which doesn't contain any bootloader first, then ignores the rest of partitions on the HD.

I'm not sure if I'm actually mixing concepts or if I did something wrong in the process. Can anyone see the issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is Windows 10 install UEFI or BIOS? Then just be sure to install Ubuntu in same boot mode. You still have to have Windows fast start up off for installer to correctly see existing NTFS partitions. What brand/model system? Post this: `sudo parted -l` Something Else: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot gpt partitioning which for a data drive for Windows and Ubuntu boot drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Is GRUB installed on the HDD or the SSD or not at all? What happens when you boot from the SSD? In this situation I would install grub on one of the drives and always set the BIOS to boot from it. You could then customize GRUB so that you are presented with a menu to boot which OS or it boots Windows by default.