# Want to dual boot pc

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual boot my pc, currently I'm using windows 10 64-bit. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop. My pc consists of two hard disk drives 500 GB and 1 TB and its BIOS mode is Legacy.
Please can anybody tell me the procedure in detail...

Comment: Which drive do you want to install Ubuntu. If on second drive, only use Something Else install option and be sure to install grub to second drive or sdb drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing & http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-optiond & Does not hightlight changing boot loader to sdb, but shows other install screenshots:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the ubuntu ISO [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).
2. Download rufus [here](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).
3. Open rufus and select your USB drive.
4. Select the options like on the picture

   [image]
5. Click on the CD icon next to "Create a bootable disk using"
6. Navigate to the ISO that you downloaded previously.
7. Click start and wait until it's complete.
8. Reboot your PC and boot from USB.
9. Follow the installation steps and choose install ubuntu alongside windows boot loader.

   [image]
10. Wait until finished and enjoy your Dualboot!

Comment: I want to install it on my first drive 500 GB

Comment: And should I also backup my windows?

Comment: @abee1993 than you can choose something else and choose your 500GB drive. the rest should be all the same. And yes to be completely sure backup. Mistakes can always be made.