# Was ubuntu installed on a different drive? Error: no such device: ... Entering grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

Recently had a PC go down that was dual booting ubuntu14 and WIN 7. I did not build or setup this PC. It had three drives:

1. 1TB SSD
2. 160GB HDD
3. 2TB HDD

On start up received this message:
Error: no such device: ... Entering grub rescue...

Found that a 2TB HDD had stop spinning. Replaced with 500GB SSD. Still receiving error. Still receiving error. I am guessing that ubuntu was stored on that 2TB HDD and the drive that had WIN 7 on it is on the other the SSD. Because in grub rescue I input and receive:

```
grub rescue>ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2)

grub rescue>ls (hd0)

(hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
```

...and the same for the rest of the partitions

I made a USB boot repair dive and ran the report given here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25027438/

I only see WIN 7 on in the OS listing on line 232. So I guess I need to reinstall ubuntu on another drive?

Comment: You show an old wubi install in sda. Was that your Ubuntu install? Otherwise no Ubuntu installs shown. Best to restore a Windows boot loader to sda as it is a Windows drive. If installing Ubuntu in BIOS mode to another drive only use Something Else and choose to install grub to MBR of that drive.Does not hightlight changing boot loader to sdb, if external drive, but shows other install screenshots:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-optiond

Comment: oldfred thanks for the reply and confirming what I thought. I am going to install WIN 10 and Ubuntu on the new SSD. Should I install WIN 10 first then Ubuntu or Ubuntu then WIN 10?

Comment: If BIOS installs always best to install Windows first. Even with UEFI generally better to install Windows first. Windows with a clean install wants lots of partitions especially if UEFI. With Ubuntu I do prefer to partition in advance with gparted and then use Something Else to choose (change button) which partition is / (root) & perhaps /home partition. If hardware is newer and UEFI, just be sure to install both systems in same boot mode. And both Windows & Ubuntu install in same boot mode as you boot installer. So be sure to use same boot mode UEFI or BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu was stored on a different dive, the 2TB HDD. So the best thing to do was to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04.2 on the new SSD along with Windows 10. As user: oldfred mention in the comments of the question. I had to install both OS in UEFI for them to work properly with this MSI 970A-G43 PLUS mobo. Because otherwise it would boot into Windows 10 and not Grub for OS selection.