# install ubuntu 22.04lts on extra internal HD

Tags: system-installation

I have 2 HDDs one with windows (unbootable) and the other with a working ubuntu 16.04lts + esm. I have a new HD to add to the system and want to install ubuntu 22.04 on this from a downloaded iso on a usb. My machine is legacy BIOS only. I will use the standard installation without partitions, but how do I ensure that the new unformatted HD is used and not the current ubuntu or windows drives?
Sorry if this seems elementary but it is years since I last did this and it included lots of partitioning that now appears to be unnecessary.

Comment: You've not said which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system you're asking about as that influences the installer being used, eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses `ubiquity`, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses `subiquity`, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *flavors* vary... etc. If using BIOS you don't need ESP, so I'd just use the "*Something else*" (assuming Desktop) so you can tell the installer & you're away.  FYI:  That stills works on 23.04 with the new *Desktop Installer* have done it days ago in QA, but ensure the Summary screen matches what you want.  Of course make backups; as mistakes are just so easy...

Comment: Another thought... ensure you write the ISO to thumb-drive in the suggested way in documentation (*the tool used doesn't matter as much; just don't use apps that can re-order the ISO unless you know how those changes will work on your actual hardware configuration*); direct cloning methods are in my opinion still safest  (*No Ubuntu Desktop release has ever required an ESP, but you can make it appear mandatory to the installer because of ISO write method so be careful; as you have less control on where ESP is written in my experience - thus it could go to different drive than you selected*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot With Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953890/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot-with-windows-7)

Comment: If you temporarily remove your existing hard drives and then install Ubuntu 22.04 normally to the new hard drive you can not break your old drives. Once 22,04 is installed, replace the old drives, set the new drive as first HDD, and run `sudo update-grub` to add the old drives to the GRUB boot menu.

Comment: @karel: That question was closed five years ago.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I would like to reopen that question now. Would you help me to fight the apathy and neglect by voting to reopen it? I'll vote to reopen it too if you do.

Comment: @karel: So voted. The duplicated Questions do not look duplicated by that question to me.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Do you want to post an answer somewhere? I faced this same situation and the accepted answer to the linked question was how I solved it, but maybe there is a another/better way of doing it now.

Comment: @karel: My step-by-step instructions for installing Ubuntu to a different internal or external BIOS boot drive are on one of the duplicated/non-duplicated/merged questions linked to on one of the duplicated questions: https://askubuntu.com/a/983692/43926

Comment: Thank you all - I have been ill and only just got round to installing Ubuntu 22.04 on the new hard drive following @C.S.Cameron advice and it worked perfectly. However it is very different from 16.04 esm so I want to continue using this for a time and have it set as the first HDD. But updating grub does not add the new drive (Ubuntu 22.04) to the boot menu so to use it I have to change boot order in the BIOS each time. How can I get all 3 drives in the grub menu?