# Installing Ubuntu OS on a separate drive with dual boot Windows

Tags: 18.04

I already looked at the [Installing Ubuntu on a separate drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot) question, but it was all about resizing partitions on an existing Windows drive rather than placing the Ubuntu OS on a separate hard drive.

I want to be able to choose the OS on startup.

Comment: Boot your install 'live' media; and select 'try ubuntu' to ensure it you're happy. Then you can click install selecting 'something else', then partition drives however you want (using your second disk). You'll be asked where to install grub, select your 'boot' drive (as defined in bios) and you'll have the grub menu to select which will boot. [*note I'm assuming mbr/bios boot; you didn't specify eufi or bios, but this is a pretty standard install, just not as common as a single drive*]

Comment: Yes that sounds like the way to go. Thanks Xen2050 & guiverc

Comment: If I understand it correctly (bear with me new to Linux stuff) I proceed with the LiveUSB boot to it...try then like then install to 'something else' make sure to put the 'Grub' in the 'Primary Drive' in this case C:\ drive that has Win7 then proceed to create a  /home partition for storage with NO  'swap'  files and continue on with a full install of Ubuntu. Making double sure I have all in the correct drives. In my case the 'Secondary' drive is E:\ that has the empty SSD and it being the 'separate' drive that I wish to place Unbuntu in. I really wish that Linux could recognize drives.

Comment: What I mean by recognize drives is call it out by make rather than the number of mb's it has or their own nomenclature (sga1 sga2 etc)