# I can't install Ubuntu 18.4 in my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu 18.4 on a separate hard drive in a dual boot but when I used this link [How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot) but after I start, installing my installing crashed and when I try to shutdown laptop my screen freezes. Is there another solution to install Ubuntu on a separate hard drive in a dual boot?
If there is Please explain it step by step. Thanks

I have n552v Asus laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an installation media issue. Try to create a new boot disk with a new iso.
Also since you are doing this on a separate drive you can remove the original one to make sure it doesn't get formated during installation. This isn't absolutely necessary just an easy precaution. Then you can just refresh the grub menu to find the other os.

Worst case scenario you can try to install Linux onto your drive on a different computer and then plug it into your laptop afterwards.