# Dual Boot Not Working on HP Envy Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

This question is related to dual booting of windows and ubuntu 20.04 on separate hdd in the same laptop.  I have been using ubuntu 20.04 on a very old stand alone desktop tower which has finally stopped working.  I have now installed ubuntu 20.04 on the second hdd2 in a slightly younger HP Envy laptop with windows installed on the other hdd1.  I followed the instructions to the letter when installing ubuntu 20.04 including the need to ensure that the hdd1 was specified for the boot function.  However, after installing ubuntu 20.04, when I first switched the laptop on it would only booted to Windows.  I then used the Windows Command to install the grub using command "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubX64.efi".  Now I get a black panel in which the first line in the box is "grub>" which is clearly expecting me to enter something.  Nothing I enter helps.

When I checked the Boot Order Menu (press F10 on boot up) I noted that there is no hard drive option (just a boot manager option plus cd drive and network drive options) mentioned in the UEFI boot order list.  The boot manager is at the top of the list. However below in the Legacy boot order list a hard drive option is shown.  Note that I switched off legacy, fast boot, and secure boot as per the ubuntu 20.04 installation instructions so they are greyed out. Note that a ubuntu option does **not** appear in the UEFI boot order list

If I press F9 on boot up I get the Boot Selection Menu. If I select the EFI option I get another panel with a long string.  If I select the string I get another panel with a EFI option at the bottom of the list.  If I select the EFI option then I get yet another panel where the list has a grubX64.efi option.  If I select the grubX64.efi option I then get the black panel listing various boot options including the windows option with ubuntu at the top. Hey presto ubuntu 20.04 is launched and runs beautifully!  However this is a long winded way to get there.

I have also run Boot Repair which tells me that it has repaired the boot.  However still does the same thing.

I noted that when I installed ubuntu I left the entry for the boot drive as it was.  Should I have selected one of the other hdd1 directories listed (there were a number of them)? Note that the ubuntu install instructions were not specific about making such a selection. How do I get the grub into the windows boot manager option in the boot order panel where I presume I would then get the correct behaviour when I switch the laptop on.

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the instructions to the letter when installing ubuntu >20.04 including the need to ensure that the hdd1 was specified >for the boot function.

According to your descriptions , i think you may make some mistakes when installing Ubuntu .

The boot loader should be installed on the disk where Ubuntu is located.
The recommended practice is:
Create a new partition in HDD2 to use as EFI (when installing Ubuntu via LiveCD) Install the boot loader into this partition.

The installer will do the rest automatically.

Not sure if we can solve the problem

Comment: I have just found <https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot> which says to create a EFI partition.  I did not do that so I will reformat sdb and follow the instructions from that site.

Comment: I have eventually have the dual boot start up operating correctly.  I went into windows aand deleted the sdb partitions and reformatted to ext4.  Following this I tried to repair the mbr by creating a system repair disc but got stuck with the disc in the drive and the process stopped.  I managed to get the windows repair page by pressing f11 on boot up and followed the process shown in sections 4 and 5 here https://windowsreport.com/fix-windows-10-grub-rescue/#3

Comment: My previous comment was incomplete so will continue here.  I gave up trying to repair the windows boot and went ahead with reinstalling Ubuntu on sdb including creating an EFI partition in sdb and assigning sdb as the device for the boot loader.  I am now able to select which operating system to boot up and have successfully booted to Windows and to Ubuntu on separate occasions. My thanks to you for the help.

Comment: It means you have solved this problem. Congratulate!