Ubuntu 24.04 installation error
My Laptop has two hard disks, SSD and HDD, the SSD with 256GB has Windows installation, and the HDD with 1TB is divided into two partitions D and F, each of which has nearly half.
I noticed that the Laptop is hanging and running slower, so you decided to install Ubuntu on one of the HDD partitions, whereas the SDD is for Windows installations, and the D partition is for Data in Windows, so I need to install Ubuntu on the F partition.
First of all from "Computer Management" I clicked on "Delete Volume", to make the F partition unallocated.
Then I installed Ubuntu  24.04 and burned it on USB flash using Rufus
choose USB from the boot menu
then choose "Try or install Ubuntu"
and so on, but the installation is incomplete, and an error occurs.


There was a helpful post ~5 years ago that seems to have some steps (w/ screenshots) that might help guide your install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot It might also help the community if you include additional information about the full installation process you took (installation choices you made) to get to where you are, now. The information you provided is very high-level.
